# External USB HDD

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hdd, smart

How to fix External USB HDD:

```
Health 0%
Failure Predicted - Attribute: 5 Reallocated Sectors Count, Count of sectors moved to the spare area. Indicate problem with the disk surface or the read/write heads.
There are 16376 bad sectors on the disk surface. The contents of these sectors were moved to the spare area.
Based on the number of remapping operations, the bad sectors may form continuous areas.
Replace hard disk immediately.

It is recommended to backup immediately to prevent data loss.
```

Comment: BACKUP THE ENTIRE DISK IMMEDIATELY! It will soon be physically and irreparably broken.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix any more. That drive will fail and probably soon.

**Get a new drive and rescue your data!**

Until you have the new HDD, keep the faulty one unplugged. **If you keep using it, you risk data loss.**

Get a copy of [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) and put it on a CD or USB flash drive to boot. If you don't know Clonezilla, it allows you to mirror the content of one drive to another. Use it to backup your data!

**Seriously**: No more writing to the disk! Read from it *only* for backup.